# GLSL - Trying to blend vertex color lightmaps and textures

Tags: opengl, glsl, rendering, blending

I am working with an old game format and am trying to finish up a rendering project. I am working on lighting and am trying to get a multiply blend mode going in my shader.

The lighting is provided as vertex values which are they interpolated over the triangle.

I have taken a screenshot of an unlit scene, and just the light maps and put them in Photoshop with a multiply layer. It provides exactly what I want.
I also want to factor in the ambient light which is kind of a like a 'Opacity' on the Photoshop color layer.
I have tried just multiplying them, which works great but again, I want to be able to control the amount of the lightmaps. I tried mix, which just blended the lightmaps and the textures but not in a multiply blend.

Here are the images. The first is the diffuse, the second is the lightmap and the third is them combined at 50% opacity with the lightmaps.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sscod.png [1]

So, my question is, how do I multiply blend these with the sort of ambient light "opacity" factor. Again, I have tried a direct mix but it's more of an overlay, rather than a multiply blend.
My GLSL fragment source:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
varying vec2 outtexture; in vec4 colorout;
void main(void)
{
    float ambient = 1.0f;

    vec4 textureColor = texture2D(texture, outtexture);
    vec4 lighting = colorout;

    // here is where I want to blend with the ambient light dictating the contribution from each
    gl_FragColor = textureColor * lighting;
}
```

Comment: As a side note: you are using `in vec4 colorour;` which is not valid syntax for GLSL 1.20, you shoudl use `varying` for that.

Comment: @derhass Interesting. It compiles and does not lose information. But thanks, i'll fix that.